# ASP.NET MVC passing a value from a variable on a controller to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, viewmodel

I´m trying to pass a value from a variable `var profit = income - expenses` that is inside of an ActionResult on controller.
Does anyone know how is it possible to call this variable on a view? (With a short example please) Or do I need to make a table on purpose to store de value of the variable?

Comment: You can store it in the ViewData or ViewBag and access it in the view using ViewData or ViewBag

Comment: You can pass it inside statement :- Return View() if nothing is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a value that just needs to be available in the view, at this current time you could use `ViewData` to handle this.

You could set the value on the Controller

```
ViewData["Profit"] = profit;
```

Then you could display that value in the view

```
@ViewData["Profit"]
```

There are other options, but this would be the "fastest" route.

Here is a [tutorial showing usage of ViewData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/nerddinner/use-viewdata-and-implement-viewmodel-classes?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4025428)